# Simple Method to a Simple Parser

Tags: c++, parsing, analysis, lexical

I'm trying to create a simple parser and a small text file which follows the following **structure**:

> Variable_name = Value;
>
> VARIABLE_2 = SECOND_VALUE;

**Found methods that work**, however, **use many librarys** like Boost. I wonder if you can make a **simple, preferably with only the librarys of *STD***.

Thanks, Bruno Alano.

Comment: For a case like yours you can split on ` = ` and have what is in left side as variable and what is in right as value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your format will be staying like you have listed, and there will be no spaces in either the variable names or the values, this is can be done easily using a combination of `std::string` and `std::istringstream`.  You could simply do the following:

```
//assume we have an open ifstream object called in_file to your file
string line;
getline(in_file, line);

while (in_file.good())
{
    char variable[100];
    char value[100];
    char equals;

    //get rid of the semi-colon at the end of the line
    string temp_line = line.substr(0, line.find_last_of(";"));
    istringstream split_line(temp_line);

    //make sure to set the maximum width to prevent buffer overflows
    split_line >> setw(100) >> variable >> equals >> value;

    //do something with the string data in your buffers

    getline(in_file, line);
}
```

You can change the types of `variable` and `value` to properly fit your needs ... they don't need to be `char` buffers, but can be any other type provided that `istream& operator>>(istream&, type&)` is defined for the data-type you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

If variables and values cannot contain equal signs or semicolons and you can assume the file will always be well-formed this is trivial to do.

Grab everything until you reach a semicolon. Split the string at the `=` sign. The first part is your variable name. The second part is the value.

If you have to deal with comments, string literal values (that may contain `=` or `;`) this is **NON-TRIVIAL** and you should use `boost.Spirit`.

If you're wondering how to split a string, there's many questions asked about the topic and a particularly good one is: [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Its basically not dissimilar to an INI file.

Quick search comes up with this:
http://code.google.com/p/inih/

Which has minimal dependencies.

If you need to, it is probably pretty easy to strip out the section handling.

You'd need to add in handling for the semicolons though, which are normally the start of comments in INI files.

Its a starting point, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [lemon parser generator](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/), it generates a file with no dependencies beside stdlibc. [Here](http://freshmeat.net/articles/lemon-parser-generator-tutorial) is a good starting tutorial.

As a scanner, I prefer [re2c](http://re2c.org/), which is also public domain.

You could wrap the `yyparse()` function in a C++ class, if you really need C++.

Comment: The lemon parser is good, but it's pretty much focused on C isn't it?

Comment: C and C++ can interoperate. Just use `extern "C"`. All the parser generators for C++ will give you a class (and many with additional crap which you said you don't want), that's the point of C++. With C, you get a function, which you can embed however you like.

Answer (score 1):

The really short (C-style) method would be something like:

```
scanf("%s = %[^\n]", variable_name, value);
```